# Add a function to the prototype with access to "this"

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

On the one hand I can assign a new function to an object with
`Object.defineProperty(...)`.

Then I tried to assign a function directly to the NodeList Prototype. But somehow it doesn't work properly. What am I doing wrong?

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  NodeList.prototype,
  'lastElement', { 
    get: function() {
      return this[this.length - 1].textContent;
    }
  }
);

NodeList.prototype.firstElement = () => {
   return this[0].textContent;
}

const h = document.querySelectorAll('span');
console.log('#last:', h.lastElement);
console.log('#first:', h.firstElement);
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions `() => {...}`  are not just a different syntax that behaves the same way, they actually handle the `this` keyword differently.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods

If you switch to using the traditional function syntax, `this` will behave as you are expecting.

Additionally, you've defined `firstElement` as a regular function, not a getter function, so you will need to call it like this

```
console.log('#first:', h.firstElement());
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  NodeList.prototype,
  'lastElement', { 
    get: function() {
      return this[this.length - 1].textContent;
    }
  }
);

NodeList.prototype.firstElement = function() {
   return this[0].textContent;
}

const h = document.querySelectorAll('span');
console.log('#last:', h.lastElement);
console.log('#first:', h.firstElement());
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it still possible to write it so that the assigning function still gets a getter? So that I can call it without `()`?

Comment: I don't think so, I think you are limited to the method you used for `lastElement`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I learned something today :-) Merci